# Set a Bash variable using PowerShell Core on Linux

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to define a Bash variable using PowerShell on Linux, example code below:

```
pwsh
bash -c 'database="db1"'
bash -c 'echo $database'
<no output>
```

I have also tried:

```
$scriptText = "database='db1'"
Invoke-Expression -Command $scriptText
The term 'database=db1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Edit: I am trying to set the `umask` value, e.g.

```
umask = 0022
```

OS: Oracle Linux 8.5
PowerShell version: 7.1.5

Comment: Powershell and Bash are independent of each other. [Edit] the question and explain in plain English what you are trying to achieve by setting the environment variables anyway, so we can suggest the right way.

Comment: variable assignments in PowerShell must include the `$`: `$database = 'db1'`. If you want a bash child process to inherit an environment variable `database`, do `$env:database = 'db1'` in PowerShell before launching bash

Comment: `bash -c 'database="db1"'` starts a subshell, sets a variable in it and exit. The scope of the variable doesn't extend outside the shell so obviously subshells and parent shells can't see it. In bash to set environment variables you need to use `export`

Comment: @vonPryz I am trying to set the `umask` value from PowerShell - not sure if it is possible..

Comment: Google setting environment variables in Oracle Linux (/etc/profile ?)